# Gmail IMAP using OAuth 2.0 and Service Account fails with status 400

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, gmail-imap, google-apps-marketplace, service-accounts

When I try to connect to the Gmail IMAP server using XOAUTH2 mechanism and Service Account, I get the following response:

```
{"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
```

The code I use in PHP is:

```
$email = "an_user@of_a_domain.com";

require_once 'GoogleApiClient/Google_Client.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setUseObjects(true);

$gac = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    "xxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    'https://mail.google.com/',
    file_get_contents("path/to/private/key"),
    'notasecret',
    'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',
    $email
);

$client->setApplicationName("Test App");
$client->setAssertionCredentials($gac);

$client::$auth->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
$token = $client::$auth->getAccessToken();

$authStr = base64_encode("user=" . $email . "\1auth=Bearer " . $token . "\1\1");
$response = send_command_to_imap("TAG1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 " . $authStr);
```

Following instructions at http://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth2-gmail-imap-service-account I authorized access to mail. (And then reinstalled the app in my test domain, of course) But I still get it failed.

I can get the token okay, but could not authenticate to the IMAP.

I've also tried to access Gmail IMAP for non-domain google users (access token includes "offline_token") w/o using Service Account - and it worked just fine for me!

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've found the problem why it fails. I just need to json_decode `$token` and use `$token['access_token']` value and not entire json string the Google returns.

Answer (score -1):

Since last io2014 there is now a much easier way to integrate with Gmail :

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/overview

Comment: Yes, I know, but I need IMAP because Gmail API does not have few cool things that IMAP has :)